# Manifest is malformed when installing app on Android 7 (API 24)

Tags: android, kotlin, manifest, google-play-console

I have an Android app that would not install on a Samsung S6 running Android 7. It would not install both from the Play Store and directly from Android Studio deployment.

I checked logcat and it stated that I have a package/class listed in my manifest as `Managers.MyApp`. I indeed had a folder named Managers and so files in there used the same name for their package.

I renamed the folder plus all references to managers (lowercase m). I did a global search to make sure there were no remnants. The app was finally successfully deploying to the Android 7 Samsung S6.

I uploaded the app to `Internal Testing` in Play Console (where the Samsung device would previously also fail to install the app from, with the same error). This time it was able to install from internal testing, so surely all is well with the app.

However, when I released the app to production, the Samsung device is again unable to install the app, showing the same error as before: Malformed manifest, invalid class: Managers.MyApp.

I do not have any instances of `Managers` anymore with an uppercase `m`. I checked the manifest and it certainly has `managers.MyApp`.

Is there some caching going on with Play Console? Or are there extra steps I need to implement. MyApp is a class that extends `Application`.

Comment: I do not have access to the exact error at this point in time.

Comment: Maybe try using the fully qualified name in the `name` field?

Comment: @Tenfour04 ok I will do that when I get a chance. Will update you. It is however unfortunate that I do not see this issue until I have made a release. So we are talking about days worth of waiting for the release to be approved by Google first.